# Winform hidden when opening via remote desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-desktop

I have a windows forms application that is not displaying in some remote desktop situations.  Locally, it works fine.  When using on a server via terminal services, it works fine.

However, when remoting directly to a workstation, it will display as an icon in the taskbar and can be right-clicked to close or move, but the form is not visible.  I thought maybe it's location was outside of the screen, but I've tried right-clicking the icon an moving it and the "move" cursor shows up in the middle of the screen where I would expect the application to be.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is this user account or permission related?

Comment: Do you use custom painting for the form at all? (or any skinning component that might use custom painting). Using transparency?

Comment: I have a few custom controls that call Graphics.DrawString() and ControlPaint.DrawBorder().  Is that the kind of thing you're referring to?

Comment: Nope, thinking about the form itself. Custom painting and transparency on forms is known to cause issues with RDP. Just as a test, can you disable bitmap caching for your RDP session and see if that helps? (should be on the RDP connection performance options)

Answer (score 1):

Upon physically visiting the workstation that was being logged into remotely, it was discovered that the form was on the OTHER monitor.

Facepalm();